# Text direction change for print check

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm working on an application where I need to print data on check leaf, but I'm confused how to make the text direction from left -> right to bottom -> top?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Graphices. DrawString method, then there is a StringFormat argument. Use DirectionVertical to draw vertical text.

Comment: Yes same .. `string Name = textBox1.Text;
            var g = e.Graphics;
            g.DrawString(Name, new Font("Tahoma", 8), Brushes.Black, 100, 20,
            new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical));`

This worked for me.